# Nodejs - Missing first character in error prototype name in stack trace when failing chai test case

Tags: node.js, express, mocking, stack-trace, chai

I'm using Express and I'm writing a test for some part of my code using Chai.

At some point, the tested code is expecting the `next()` function from Express, so I'm mocking it by making a very simple function like follows:

```
var next = function(err) {
  if (err) {
    done(err)
  } else {
    done(
  }
}
```

Meaning that if the mocked `next()` function receives an `err`, then it would fail the test by calling `done(err)`, and if not, if will successfully finish the test by calling `done()`.

Now, this seems to be working, but for the case when an `err` is received, I'm getting a truncated stacktrace in the test output. Suppose the error received is of prototype `SomeError` which in turn extends the default `Error` prototype, then in the console I see the following:

```
 omeError
  at Foo.bar.yeah (lib/foo/bar/yeah.js:78:12)
  at Blah.someFunction (node_modules/yeah/lib/index.js:145:16)
```

Note the missing capital `S` in `omeError` when in fact it should be `SomeError`.

Btw, if I do a `console.log(err)` I get the following:

```
{ [SomeError]
  foo: 'bar',
  foo2: 'yeah'
  name: 'SomeError' }
```

So, it seems the error object has a correct name `SomeError`. Altough I'm not sure why the string representation of the error also includes `[SomeError]` as a first line, in which seems a non-json syntax...

Why is this happening? I'm assuming something asyncronous failing to capure the complete stacktrace or something like that? Or could it be related to how `SomeError` extends `Error`. None of the above?